# DataTreeListView shows no results

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm using a custom control from the [ObjectListView](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/) package.

But I find it very hard to show data results in the DataTreeListView control. 
This is my code:

```
         DataSet ds = LoadDatasetFromXml("FamilyTree.xml");

         if (ds.Tables.Count > 0)
         {
             this.dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
             this.dataGridView1.DataMember = "Person";

             this.dataTreeListView1.DataMember = "Person";
             this.dataTreeListView1.DataSource = new DataViewManager(ds);
         }
```

And this is the result:

[image: result]

I use the xml that's provided with the package, so that won't be the problem. I changed all the dataTreeListView properties so they are just the same as the demo project.

I also tried it using Linq with an selfmade table but with the same results. The datagridview on the other hand works like a charm...

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```
this.dataTreeListView1.KeyAspectName = "Id";
this.dataTreeListView1.ParentKeyAspectName = "ParentId";
// to tell DataTreeListView about first row(rows) don't have parent, root rows
this.dataTreeListView1.RootKeyValue = 0;
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to add some explanation regarding why you expect this to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing following code blocks:

```
  dataTreeListView1.KeyAspectName = "Id";
  dataTreeListView1.ParentKeyAspectName = "ParentId";
```

Comment: Please add code formatting to make the solution easier to read. http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help